What are questions that used to be handled in Music.SE but are now more appropriate to MusicFans.SE?
When I see the list in "Ask about..." in Music Fans's tour:

The history of songs and people who make and create music
Song meanings and the origins of lyrics
Terminology used in the music industry
Use, explanation, and history of music technology, devices, and media
Information about music memorabilia and the collection of it

I see potential overlap in #1 (esp. classical compositions and composers) and #4 (I see a lot of questions on audio devices in Music.SE).  I wonder whether there are other types of questions that are now more suitable for Music Fans.
Is there a guideline on which questions should now be asked in Music Fans instead?

The Ask About list is still the correct list. The guidelines are generally that here questions should focus on practice and performance, and on Music Fans they should focus on those topics more relevant to fans.
It is okay that we have overlap - most Stack Exchange sites overlap with at least one other - but as a brief correction, we don't overlap much on #1, and even on #4 there are distinct areas which work better on one site or the other.
